# PHP Try Catch logical correct

Tags: php

I have this try and catch:

```
try {
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("Select ...");
    $stmt->execute() or die(Log::error("DB-Error (Reservation): ", ['error' => $stmt->errorInfo()]));
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    Log::error("DB-Error (Reservation): ", ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => (int)$e->getCode()]);
    return false;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    Log::error("Error (Reservation): ", ['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
    return false;
}
```

I have 1 questions:

1. Is this one needed: `$stmt->execute() or die(Log::error("DB-Error (Reservation): ", ['error' => $stmt->errorInfo()]));` or can I simply use `$stmt->execute() or die();` because I catch the error later?

Comment: There should be no `die` at all. _If_ you let the script die at this point, then there will be no catching of anything _later_ - dead is dead.

Comment: Not sure if it is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318368/mysqli-or-die-does-it-have-to-die (although that is myqli not pdo - but the principle is the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is should be no `die` you can try code below:

```
try {
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("Select ...");
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    Log::error("DB-Error (Reservation): ", ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => (int)$e->getCode()]);
    return new stdClass();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    Log::error("Error (Reservation): ", ['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
    return new stdClass();
}
```

Comment: When I use this in PHPStorm, I get this notice `Undefined class 'stdClass'`